# Why can't we manually iterate through a LinkedList?

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

`LinkedList` is a data structure, in which each element is coupled with a link to its next element.

So, in theory, this data structure is made for freely iterating through a list, in whichever direction, while performing whatever operations (except, maybe, deleting the element you're currently at).

However, in application, this isn't true. Returning an Iterator from a LinkedList is subject to the general `Iterator` rules (i.e. no modifying while iterating), and even creating a `ListIterator`, an improved `Iterator`, which allows modifying the next/previous element of the iterator, and let's you go forward/backward dynamically, still has severe limitations:

You can't delete elements from the beginning of the list if you're not currently there, and neither can you add elements to the end of the list, unless you're currently there.

So, is there a way to iterate freely through a `LinkedList` while performing whatever modifications to the list? And if not, why isn't there one? Shouldn't it be one of the main goals of this data structure to realize it?

Comment: You should very rarely use `LinkedList`. For most applications `ArrayList` or `ArrayDeque` will give you at least as good an API (also for inserting and deleting in the middle) and better performance. I used a `LinkedList` once in my 17 years career as Java programmer, and in retrospect I made the wrong choice when I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice to make *all* Iterators failfast was a design decision, just that and nothing more.

Nothing stops you to take the code and starting from that, build a NotSoFailFastIterator for yourself if you think you can use it.  However I think you'll quickly revert from using it once yoy see its behaviour and its results in usage scenarios where there's *really* lots of concurrent activity going on on the underlying List of your iterator.

Comment: Well, I'm not looking into coherency behavior yet, but I guess that point holds. However, there's no next() in a LinkedList, at least not this version: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: Yeah sorry I was just looking what the chain of methods was to get to the next() from the internal structures.  Alas, I found they're not exposed at all so I'll edit that remark away again.

Comment: I agree with this answer. JDK implements commonly used features. If you need some specific behaviours, just implement it by yourself or use some frameworks.

Comment: Another point: Doesn't using a ListIterator concurrently with a regular Iterator the same kind of problems as my approach?

Comment: A change applied through iterator1 will be a change not applied through iterator2 therefore after the change, any usage of iterator2 will indeed fail with a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: @ErwinSmout In that case, ListIterator should already have all the problems my iterator has - we can't have a ListIterator and an Iterator run concurrently, and even less two ListIterators.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is not specific to `LinkedList`s. When you iterate over a `List` (any `List`) with a `ListIterator`, you can only make structural changes (adding or removing elements) in the current position of the iterator. Otherwise, continuing to use the iterator after a structural change of the `List` may yield unexpected results.

For adding elements to the start or end of the `LinkedList`, you have `addFirst` and `addLast` methods. You don't have to iterate over the `List` in order to do that.

A `ListIterator` instance maintains a state that allows it to locate the next and previous elements as well as support other operations (remove the current element, add an element at the current position). If you make a structural change to a `List` not via the `ListIterator`, the state of the iterator may become invalid, leading to unexpected results. Therefore all structural changes must be made via the `ListIterator`.

I guess that the `LinkedList` class could supply an implementation of a more complex iterator that  supports operations such as `addFirst` and `addLast`. I'm not sure how useful that would have been, and whether it would justify the added complexity.

Comment: No, but I may want to iterate while modifying the list. In that case no matter which iterator I use, it will still fail

Comment: @Sudix You can add and remove elements with a ListIterator, meaning you can iterate while modifying the list?

Comment: @Jorge.V yes, you can, but only at the current position of the iterator.

Comment: @Eran Well yeah, thats "iterating while modifying". If you want to do it in random positions, you are not even iterating or using an iterator to begin with. I don't really understand what Sudix said about wanting to iterate while modifying the list failing.

Comment: @Jorge.V Let's say I'm a detective and I've got a list of important information. To solve my case, I need to deduce from all my information. So I'm iterating through my list, clue for clue, but ever so often I get a call that some new hint has turned up. So I mark where I was currently at my list, and write the new hint to the end of the list, then return to where I currently was.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate freely use array or list. Linked lists are meant to be traversed and access the data useful in dynamic allocation of the memory to the data.

Comment: `LinkedList` is a subclass of `List`, so it should be as suitable as any available list. An array has to be resized frequently, and so only has amortized constant cost for adding an element

Answer (score 0):

When you have a linked list datastructure, you can add or remove at a particular node, when your cursor is pointing to the right node where you want to add or remove.

> Inserts the specified element into the list (optional operation). The
>   element is inserted immediately before the element that would be
>   returned by next(), if any, and after the element that would be
>   returned by previous(), if any.  The new element is inserted before
>   the implicit cursor: a subsequent call to next would be unaffected,
>   and a subsequent call to previous would return the new element. (This
>   call increases by one the value that would be returned by a call to
>   nextIndex or previousIndex.)

[ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)

Instead if its a array structure, then you access by index , and it is possible to add or remove at a particular index limited , by the length of the array. ArrayList does that.